# Android Layout Text at Left and Image at Right

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I am trying to to make a list where image stay on the right of the layout all the time. At the same time if there is no image I will like the subject text to fill the whole layout.

This is what I hope to achieve 
When Image is Hide
[image]

With Image
[image]

Current output:
The image at the front on the text.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dip" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:textColor="#8000FF"       
        android:text="Date" />
    <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/subject"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...cheers :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="6dip" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subject"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:text="Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:textColor="#8000FF"       
    android:text="Date" />
```

Comment: A more efficient way to woud be to use a textview with a compound drawable.

Answer (score 1):

you should do like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mark_ok" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftblock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange Apple Orange" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#8000FF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you light up the reason for your "should"? Cleaner?

Comment: In relative layout containing 2 blocks, the left block is never overlapped by the right if specify: layout_toLeftOf="<id_of_the_right_item_(the icon)>"

Comment: The "@+" is very important, because it refers to a view that hasn't been created yet :)